# custom action bar image - app crashes

Tags: android, image, action

Hi Im having trouble with setting custom background on my action bar. I wan for every single intent custom image on acton bar.

I've already tried this

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_picture));
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

but the app crashes with error

```
          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lowrider.menuapp/com.example.lowrider.menuapp.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: You might need to call `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Comment: you're right it worked

Answer (score 0):

You should use getSupportActionBar() and not getActionBar().

```
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_picture));
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```